# Configuration files are ignored after migrating to Servicemix 5

Tags: apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

We use a .cfg file in ./etc directory to configure our bundle in ServiceMix. Everything worked fine in SMX 4.5.3, but when migrating to the 5th version the file is not picked up. When the bundle encounters a property the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property with key [xslt.dir] not found in properties from text: {{xslt.dir}}, StackTrace: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property with key [xslt.dir] not found in properties from text: {{xslt.dir}}
```

However, if I put the properties in default-properties section in my blueprint configuration, it works.

Also, the console command config:list actually shows the properties for the bundle in spite of the exception:

```
Pid:            misrouter
BundleLocation: mvn:ru.mig/mis-router/1.0-SNAPSHOT
Properties:
   service.pid = misrouter
   felix.fileinstall.filename = file:/home/petr/programs/5.0.0-apache-servicemix/etc/misrouter.cfg
   xslt.dir = /home/petr/programs/5.0.0-apache-servicemix/xslt
```

So was something changed in SMX 5 configuration mechanism or is there a bug in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's related to Camel *vm* component, a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SM-2285) was created for SMX

Answer (score 0):

What version of the JDK/JRE are you using?  When I was trying this out a few minutes ago to answer your question, I also had some problems using the 1.7.0_15 version I had installed and upgrading to the latest 1.7.0_51 fixed those for me.

Comment: Thank you, gertv, but updating java didn't help. However, the following Camel context configuration made it work: 
`<propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="file:./etc/misrouter.cfg"/>`
The problem is it works only sometimes, namely, after bundle deploy: if I restart SMX, the properties are ignored again, I need to redeploy the bundle; when I update the config file, the changes are not hot picked up unless I redeploy though there's a log record about update. So it looks like a bug to me, or may be I'm missing something.

Comment: Is this a Spring or Blueprint XML file you're using?  What update strategy are you using?

Comment: I'm using Blueprint XML. The update strategy was 'none', the default one, when I changed it to 'reload', hot deploy of config file started working. Also I had an outdated version of blueprint-cm schema. But still when I start SMX, the config file is ignored. Any ideas?